# How to create input text box for xss redirection

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

I want to create a simple text box for redirecting to a website. It is part of the xss which I want to implement.

```
parent.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
```

Is the code which I want to redirect but I just want to make the text box like below, and if he enters the correct or wrong text it should redirect to the website. I have only included ok but can we use cancel only so that redirection performs well?

[image: xss]

Comment: This question is really hard to understand. Can you be a bit more detaild? Also XSS is a vulnerability. Are you implementing a vulnerability?

Comment: @Erlend Actually i need to test the blog and i want to warn them as i want to become good hacker i want just to report them so i just want to design some form alert after that it should be redirected to the web page and alert should be on click